# list inteprolation removing arbitary values - np.interp

Tags: python, list, interpolation

I am new to python coding:

I have a list of temperatures, for days where temperature was not recorded the value 9999 is used. I want to use np.interp tp interpolate through the list to remove 9999, with an estimated value.
E.g.

max_temp = [40, 35, 32, 31, 9999, 9999, 9999, 26, 27, ... ... 40, 42]

Answer (score 1):

Solved - Used:

```
from pandas import *
a = [1,2,3,None,5]
b = Series(a).interpolate()
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Simpler than np.interp()